# I can't figure out why "cout" didn't work properly

Tags: c++, file-io

I wrote a code for implementing file I/O. this code contains two function - one used to write characters into text file, and the other used to read characters from text file.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int writefile(const char* f)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    char c;
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open(f);

    while (true)
   {
        cout << "input character:";
        cin >> c;
        if (cin.eof())
            break;
        ofile << c;
        cnt++;
    }
    ofile.close();
    return cnt;
}

int readfile(int n, const char* f)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(f);

    do
    {
        cout << static_cast<char>(ifile.get());
        cnt++;

    } while (cnt<n);

    cout << endl;

    ifile.close();
    return cnt;
}

int main(void)
{

    char ch;
    int num,total,sum;
    const char* filename = "test.txt";


    total = writefile(filename);

    cout << total<<" characters were written successfully." << endl;

    cout << "how many characters?";
    cin >> num;

    sum = readfile(num,filename);

    cout << sum << " characters were read successfully." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is this:
    cout << "how many characters?";
    cin >> num;

this part doesn't work. I wanted to display user-inputted number of characters originally but I couldn't input number of characters. 
I want you guys to pick what is problem.

Comment: ‘*doesn't work*’ is a very poor description of a problem. *How* does it not work? Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it result in something unexpected? Did something catch fire?

Comment: Please show us the wrong message,which will help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Is this even correct `cin >> num;***`? Does that even compile?

Comment: @Javia1492 that's probably an outline.

Comment: the result what I wanted was(in order):  I input some characters through the condole and save it into text file. 2. I input number of characters what i want to retrieve. 3. console show number of characters. but in my code, code for saving characters into file works. but code for reading characters from file doesn't work.

Comment: @SeihyungOh how did you "resolve" the issue? Did you just add `cin.clear()`?

Comment: @vsoftco yes. i just added cin.clear() only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in `writefile()` you read the stream until you reach the end of file.  Once you do that the end of file flag in `cin` will be set and `cin` will longer read from input.  You need to call [`clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) to remove the flag and continue reading.

Comment: Your answer is fine, I am however perplex why mine doesn't work, as I'm pretty sure you have to extract the EOF from the stream with `cin.unget()`. Just clearing the flag [is not enough](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following, immediately after `cout << "how many characters?";`:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // must #include <limits>    
std::cin.unget(); // THIS IS IMPORTANT
```

The first line clears the error flag of the stream, set to `ios::eofbit` since you read until EOF. The second line ignores everything left in the stream up to and including the delimiter (newline `'\n'` in this case) or EOF (however [**EOF is not discarded**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)), whichever comes first. **The last line is important** as otherwise your stream will still have the EOF in it, so you need to discard it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried your code but result wasn't what i wanted.

Comment: @SeihyungOh I'm not sure what you expect. It's working perfectly fine on my end, it writes the characters to the file then reads them back, full code here http://ideone.com/2xFrqF How do you end up the reading? On linux you need CTRL+D and on Windows CTRL+Z.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried your code. but it didn't work. after inputting numbers, program stopped.

Comment: FYI, I'm using VS2013 on windows 8.1

Comment: @SeihyungOh I don't understand. I can enter 1 2 3, then press CTRL+D (on Unix), then the program continues and asks "how many characters", to which I input 3, and finally the program reads them back from the file. Are you using exactly the code I posted? What do you mean "the program stopped"? Did it terminate? Is it expecting more input?

Comment: absolutely. I entered a b c d e f g. and press CTRL+Z(windows). then program continues and asks "how may~". I entered 3. the program reads only "a" back.

Comment: @SeihyungOh Sorry, I have no idea why it's not working on your machine. It should work, if its working on Unix and the code is portable, it should work the same on Windows. Are you sure you read from the correct file?

Answer (score 0):

In `writefile` you loop until `cin.eof`. `eof` means "end of file": explicitly, there is no more input from here. On its own, this is a permanent condition like a glass being empty: "I'm trying to take one more sip, but nothing happens!"

You can call `cin.clear()` but that's a bit weird: like filling up a used tin can. A better approach might be to test for a blank line e.g by testing

```
if (c == '\n')
```

Now the user can type characters until they are done, then they just hit enter.

You should probably treat eof as an error.